# ERROR: pg_restore COPY failed for table "xxxxx": ERROR: missing data for column "xxx"

Tags: postgresql, database-backups, pg-restore

hello first i want to restore a database by using pg_restore command.

i have a file.tar backup and i want to restore it

i create a new database name test with owner prod

then I do the command

`pg_restore -v -U prod -d test< prod202308160849.tar`

the error was i just see table and I can't see the data in it

```
pg_restore: processing data for table "public.a_telemetry"
pg_restore: from TOC entry 3365; 0 28232 TABLE DATA a_telemetry uprodasr
pg_restore: error: COPY failed for table "xxxxx": ERROR:  missing data for column "xxxx"
```

and it just skipped and got to copy for another table
in backups there no data in column xxx

how i COPY data for table "xxxx" even missing data for column "xxx" ??

i use many method theres no change in my database

Comment: Was that the only error?  I don't see how pg_restore could generate that error without having had earlier errors.  What version of pg_dump was used, and what version of pg_restore is used, and what version of database is being restored into?